# Hypergraph assignment?

Tags: python, algorithm, variable-assignment

Is there any assigment algorithm that permits to link to groups of elements (*nxm*), where the *nth* element can be linked to more than one element in *m*, but each *mth* with just one element from *n*.

The hungarian algorithm or the Min Cost Flow Problem, consists of finding a matching in a weighted bipartite graph, so it won’t work in my case.

Specific Problem :

I have a image processing task, where I want to create a cell tracking algorithm. For this I need to apply an assignment method between cells in two correlative images. One cell can divide in two new ones, so my algorithm should allow a double assignment between image I(t) and I(t+dt) ; but since cells can not come from two different cells, my algorithm can’t allow a double assignment between image I(*t+dt*) and I(*t*).

Comment: Can't you just assign each thing in I(t+dt) to the best corresponding thing in I(t)?

Comment: No because that would be a simple one to one assignment, and that doesn't work in my case.